# Jekyll theme not reading favicon

Tags: html, jekyll

I'm almost done with my personal website. All that's left is my tab icon, but my knowledge of html is pretty limited. I've placed my favicon.ico code below in the head.html with the other link and meta code, but I'm not seeing any changes. Do I have the right idea? I'm not sure what to change from the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use) instructions.

(no spaces at ends)

< link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/images/favicon.ico" >

You can see what I have here at  https://dietmocha.github.io/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That image doesn't seem to exist in your GitHub repo. Try `<link rel="shortcut icon" href="/assets/img/favicon.ico">`